# Selecting options from javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select

```
<select>
<script type="text/javascript">     
    $.get(     
      '/api/load/maron_online/470',     
      function(data){     
        var mydata = new Array();     
        var i = 0; // индекс массива материалов
        $('name', data).each(function(){     
          if($(this).text()=='MATERIAL_ID') mydata[i++] = new Array(); // массив материалов
          mydata[i-1][$(this).text()] = $(this).next().text();     
        });
        var htm = '';
      for(i in mydata) htm += "<option value=\"" + mydata[i]['TITLE'] + "\">"
    + mydata[i]['TITLE'] + "</option>";
        $('#real').html(htm);
      },     
      'xml'     
    );
</script>
</select>
```

I want to make a select option but the select tags that I added before and after javascript code did not work. I want the result to be

```
<select><option value=n>n</option><option value=x>x</value></select>
```

Comment: Did not work? Any errors? Is the mark-up wrong?

Comment: this is what i get: [link](http://img812.imageshack.us/img812/7823/resultdh.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Where is the select tag**

```
 var htm = '<select>';
      for(i in mydata) 
          htm += "<option value=\"" + mydata[i]['TITLE'] + "\">"
                      + mydata[i]['TITLE'] + "</option>";
    htm += '</select>';
 $('#real').html(htm); // make sure you have this element on the page
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var $sel= $('selectId');
var $opt = $('<option></option>');

for (...) {
    // set the value and text
    $opt.val(value);
    $opt.text(text);

    // add to the select
    $sel.append($opt);
}
```

### EDIT

I just noticed your script tag is inside your select tag. Your script tags should be at the bottom of your body tag.

Answer (score 0):

Please see the following fiddle. It might help.It creates a select tag with options as you specified.

http://jsfiddle.net/itz2k13/LtfFz/

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    var options = "";
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++){
       options += "<option value = "+i+">"+i+"</option>";
    }    
   jQuery("#select_option").append(options);
});
```